# Requirejs configuration in different file

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, config

I am using requirejs. My main.js content is like following.

```
requirejs.config({
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: true,
    packages: [],
    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min'
    }
});

require(["login"], function (loginService) {

    loginService.login('validUser');

});
```

Now, my config elements are little. But later, I will add packages, paths and others, so the **require.config** lines will increase.

1. I wanna separate **require.config** as a different file and use it?
2. If jquery load delays, does the error occurs? My other javascript files are using it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can, require your config before you require anything else, like this:

config example:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/Public/js',
    paths: {
        jquery: '../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        jqueryui: '../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min',
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryui: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
    waitSeconds: 3
});
```

and, then I load it:

```
require(['/Public/js/config.js'], function() {
    require(['home/index'], function() {                
    });
});
```

Just remember that you reference the config.js by path in the first require-statement because require.js can not resolve by baseUrl since it has not been loaded. When you get to the inner require()-statement, its loaded and you can reference dependencies relative to baseUrl.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can put the config into a separate JS file, that's not a problem. Just make sure that file is loaded prior to the *require()* call in your main code.
2. If you're using jQuery for other scripts that are not loaded via requireJS, ***you will get errors*** if they happen to load sooner than jQuery. What you need to do is ***convert all those static files into requireJS modules*** and load them all via requireJS. By using a [**define()**](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) function in each of the modules, you can set up dependencies, so all modules will wait for jQuery to load prior to executing their own code.

Comment: You can also use shims (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to avoid having to wrap defines around non-AMD JS.

Comment: Paul - that's very correct and can be used for jQuery plugins and such - for more info, see http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a multipage requirejs based project where the `requirejs.config` call is in a separate file

https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage/tree/master/www