# Make jest path more elegant

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Currently, I am using Jest as our test framework, it looks great. However, our JS has lots of nested structures. It looks like this:

```
jest.dontMock('../../../../src/js/component/sum');

describe('sum', function() {
 it('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', function() {
   var sum = require('../../../../src/js/component/sum');
   expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
 });
});
```

Basically, it is referencing the source js folder. I am trying to use `<rootDir>`. it is still not working.

```
jest.dontMock('<rootDir>/src/js/sum');
```

Can I have some advices to refactor this

EDIT: just in case to avoid some confusion, require is from node.js not require.js. The jest and require() are all using current test path as root path.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: requirejs configuration [paths](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config)?

Comment: There are lots of answers, for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653492/requirejs-configuration-in-different-file) one.

Comment: unfortunately, require is coming from node.js. It is not require.js. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook's `@providesmodule` module system to define your module like in your `some-file.js` file

```
/**
 * @providesModule SomeModuleName
 */

export function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

and use it as

```
jest.dontMock('SomeModuleName');
const sum = require('SomeModuleName').sum;

describe('sum', function() {
  it('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', function() {
   expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

more info [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#providesmodule) and check examples in Facebook repo